# Initializing an mpfr::real variable with an array of bytes

Tags: c++, mpfr

I am using the `mpfr::real` wrapper for MPFR to do fixed arbitrary precision calculations. Is there a good way to initialize the templated `mpfr::real` type to an integer of arbitray size (represented as an array of bytes)? For example, a 128 bit integer could be represented by `unsigned int[4]`.

Comment: It seems the author of mpfr C++ wrapper should have the answer. why not ask there: http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/